# Como usar Objetos PHP e Controle de transação em MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, objetos

Tenho um banco de dados com algumas tabelas, e criei uma classe pra manipulação para cada tabela do banco, um exemplo delas é uma classe para pedidos e outra pra *itensPedidos*. Cada classe manipula sua tabela, e quando uma classe precisa gravar dados em outra tabela, faço uma instancia dela pra poder alterar os dados, o que até aí consegui fazer sem problema algum.

O meu problema começou quando fui separar algumas coisas que estavam sendo realizadas juntas, como por exemplo a classe pedidos estava gravando os itens diretamente na tabela itensPedido. E deste ponto em diante é que não sei como prosseguir. O controle de transações que realizo funciona perfeitamente quando crio todas as instruções dentro do mesmo objeto:

```
private function inserir()
{
    if( !$this->verificaDados() ):
        return false;
    endif;

    $this->getCon();
    try{
        $this->con->beginTransaction();
        $s = $this->con->prepare( "INSERT INTO pedidos(cliente, total, situacao, data) VALUES(:cliente, :total, :situacao, now())" );
        $s->bindValue( ':cliente', $this->cliente->getId() );
        $s->bindValue( ':total', $this->total );
        $s->bindValue( ':situacao', $this->situacao );
        $s->execute();

        $pedido = $this->con->lastInsertId();

        $st = $this->con->prepare( "INSERT INTO itenspedido(pedido, produto, quantidade, preco, subtotal) VALUES(:pedido, :produto, :quantidade, :preco, :subtotal)" );

        foreach( $this->itens as $item ):
            $st->bindValue( ':pedido', $pedido );
            $st->bindValue( ':produto', $item->getProduto()->getId() );
            $st->bindValue( ':quantidade', $item->getQuantidade() );
            $st->bindValue( ':preco', str_replace( ',', '.', $item->getPreco() ) );
            $st->bindValue( ':subtotal', str_replace( ',', '.', $item->getTotal() ) );
            $st->execute();
        endforeach;

        $this->con->commit();

        return true;
    }catch( PDOException $e ){
        echo 'Erro: ' . $e;
        $this->con->rollBack();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Mas a questão é que quero que cada classe manipule sua própria tabela, mas não sei como colocar o controle de transações de modo que funcione juntamente com outros objetos:

```
try{
    $this->con->beginTransaction();
    $s = $this->con->prepare( "INSERT INTO pedidos(cliente, total, situacao, data) VALUES(:cliente, :total, :situacao, now())" );
    $s->bindValue( ':cliente', $this->cliente->getId() );
    $s->bindValue( ':total', $this->total );
    $s->bindValue( ':situacao', $this->situacao );
    $s->execute();

    $pedido = $this->con->lastInsertId();

        foreach( $this->itens as $item ):
            $item->setPedido($pedido);
            $item->salvar();
        endforeach;

        $this->con->commit();

        return true;
    }catch( PDOException $e ){
        echo 'Erro: ' . $e;
        $this->con->rollBack();

        return false;
    }
```

Dentro de cada método salvar, também tenho instruções beginTransaction(), commit() e rollBack(). O pedido não deveria ser gravado se desse falha na inserção de um dos itens do pedido.

Alguém poderia ajudar a solucionar esse problema?

Como eu implementaria o controle de transação no MySQL tendo influencia sobre os inserts das outras classes dentro da transação.

Agradeço pela ajuda que puderem me dar.